# How to access an array element using variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to add a variable inside a variable

How can I do it ?

Here is my code, in which I have to place $day in the place of Mon (line 9) so that it echo data from SQL database according to the day of week.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
//$timestamp = time();
$day = "" . date("D");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Time_table WHERE regd='". $_SESSION['TextBox1'] ."'   ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res['Mon']."</td>";
            echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res['time']."</td>";
            echo "<td style='width: 40%'>".$res['room_no']."</td>";
            }
        ?>
```

so that the line 9 should look like

```
echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res['$day']."</td>";
```

but it is wrong, I am able to figure it out how to do.

Comment: could you elaborate? you want to add an  item into `$res` or `$result`?

Comment: i want to make it like this but i dont know how  `echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res['Mon']."</td>";`     to `echo "<td style='width: 30%'>".$res['$day']."</td>";`

Comment: You mean `$res[$day]` ? I don't see how that could help though. Or do you have a column for every day in your table?

Comment: yes @Isac i know it is wrong but i want to know the correct usage

Comment: Then it would be better say what columns does your table have, and what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @Isac i have coloums like mon, tue, ... where $day is the date function which echo in Mon format, and coloumn is exactly in Mon format

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
echo '<td style="width: 30%">'.$res[$day].'</td>';
```

When you are accessing array elements, simply mention the variable which you are using to store the index. No need of quotes there.

Pay attention to the use of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$res['$day']` PHP actually looks for the index called $day in your array, since your SQL does not have a column names `$day` you will get an error saying the requested index was not found.

So using `$res[$day]` will pass the value of `$date` in to the array and if there exists an element for the value you passed, it will return.